# Why Splash screen keeps appearing in the background after Login screen loaded?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm setting the Splash screen icon and color through app.json:

When i tried to test the app on Android emulator it work properly, but after executing the apk the issues seems to appear again

Here is the splash screen code snippet from app.json file:

```
"platforms": [
    "ios",
    "android"
],
"version": "1.0.0",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"splash": {
    "image": "./assets/splash.png",
    "resizeMode": "contain",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffd525"
}
```

I expected the Login screen to appear as:

[image]

But it keeps appearing as:

[image]

Dependencies used:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk- 
    32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.15.2",
    "react-navigation": "3.1.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue for future reference ... as per using React Navigation package and when you gonna use Switch Navigator you have to add your Screen in a Stack Navigator then in any type of navigators including Tab or Switch or whatever else and not to add your screen directly.

The code sample in which this issue appears:

```
import {createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import AppIntroductionStackNav from './AppIntroductionStackNav';
import LoginScreen from '../Screens/LoginScreen';
import AppMainTabNav from './AppMainTabNav';


const TopLevelSwitchNav = createSwitchNavigator({
    AppIntroduction:  {
        screen: AppIntroductionStackNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
   AppLogin: {
        screen: LoginScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    AppMain: {
        screen: AppMainTabNav
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'AppIntroduction',
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
});

export default createAppContainer(TopLevelSwitchNav);
```

The right way is to add Login Screen to a Stack Navigator:

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import LoginScreen from '../Screens/LoginScreen';

const LoginStackNav = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: LoginScreen
    }
});

export default LoginStackNav;
```

and then add LoginStackNav to your Switch Navigator:

```
import {createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import AppIntroductionStackNav from './AppIntroductionStackNav';
import LoginStackNav from '../LoginStackNav';
import AppMainTabNav from './AppMainTabNav';


const TopLevelSwitchNav = createSwitchNavigator({
    AppIntroduction:  {
        screen: AppIntroductionStackNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
   AppLogin: {
        screen: LoginStackNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    AppMain: {
        screen: AppMainTabNav
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'AppIntroduction',
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
});

export default createAppContainer(TopLevelSwitchNav);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using expo ? Maybe you need to hide your splashscreen using this command `SplashScreen.hide()`

Source : `https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/`